# How to fetch an entire paginated list / refetch the entire paginated list?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a "classic" cursor based pagination of items.
I have to do two things with this items:

1. fetch all items of this list when components did mount
2. refetch all the list when a button is pressed

Using `react-apollo` for the first point my solution is:

1. use a `Query` component to load the first data set
2. when the last fetched data set is loaded I get the `endCursor` from it
3. use the `endCursor` and the `fetchMore` (from the `Query` render props) to load the next data set (passing `variables` and `updateQuery` to the `fetchMore` function)
4. if there are more results loop to #2

For the second solution:

1. I'm using `refetch` (from the `Query` render props) to reload the piece of the store with new data
2. Use the same loop of the first solution (with the `loadMore` function) to fetch other results

---

All of these implementations are not so easy to write / maintain / reuse, so my question are:

am I missing something? there is a better solution to this scenario?